# Files download queue on php

Tags: php, file, download, queue, wget

I need to implement some kind of files download queue. I plan to use wget for file download.

My question is - how to get information from wget when the file has been downloaded ?

Is it possible to setup callback or trigger on wget in order to do that ?

Also, you are welcome to recommend some other stuff instead of wget in order to use it for files download.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to wget, then I'm thinking you can execute bash scripts, i would suggest you to run a bash script in the background (one that you execute from php)

it would be a smart idea to run the bash script in the background because some large files might take really long time to download, so you would not have your user wait for the file to finish but rather leave the page and come back later and he will see whether the file is finished downloading or not.

if i was to do this, what i would do is, i will create bash script that will run wget, and when it finishes downloading it triggers some action, say updates a database, or runs a php script which will update the database and set the file status to downloaded, or if u do not wish to use databases you can have the bash script send an email to the user when the file is finished, email with the file link or something like that.

i am not sure i totally got your idea but i answered based on what i thought you meant.

anyway here is an example bash script which you can use to download files

```
#!/bin/bash

wget $1

SUBJECT="$1 is ready"
EMAIL="$2"

# Email text/message
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
echo "you can download your file using this link \n http://somesite/$1" > $EMAILMESSAGE
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

you can execute that bash script from php like this:
    shell_exec("scriptfile link email &");